# Install IDE helper file for netbeans

Tags: netbeans, autocomplete, laravel, laravel-4

I'm searching for auto complete way for Laravel 4 and found [this](https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822)
but i don't know how to use it , i have net beans 7.2 ,so how to install the file ?

Answer (score 3):

Just put the IDE helper file somewhere in your project directory and open the project in NetBeans, it will index the file and you'll be good to go. I leave it in the root of my app directory.

I use this file: https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822

Comment: I tried your method on laravel 5.6, but it is not working

Comment: Sorry @Deno, this answer is 5 years old and I haven't used either NetBeans or Laravel in almost as much time. It does look like the IDE helper file I linked has been updated regularly, though.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded this helper (https://gist.github.com/barryvdh/5227822#) and placed it in the root directory of the laravel project folder.  Restarted the netbeans.  It is working for me.